# Can I easily use a VPN to duplicate SSH Tunneling functionality?

Tags: vpn

Right now, when I want to use an unsecured wireless connection with my (Linux) laptop, I secure my connection by tunneling my traffic through a trusted computer using a variation of the method provided [here](http://lifehacker.com/237227/geek-to-live--encrypt-your-web-browsing-session-with-an-ssh-socks-proxy).

However, to the best of my knowledge, the (non-jailbroken) iPad does not allow applications to tunnel traffic through local ports.  However, it does seem to allow [certain VPN traffic](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1424).

I have never set up, or even used, a VPN before.  I'm looking for confirmation that I'm not barking up the wrong tree before I invest significant effort into setting up my own VPN server.

**If I want to secure my wireless iPad traffic over an unsecure wireless connection, would I be on the right track by looking at a VPN?**

Comment: What kind of traffic you would like to protect from your iPad. http only?

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Comment: @Serge - http primarily, ideally everything.

Comment: Then VPN is the only thing that will fulfill your needs

Comment: Any VPN with encryption enabled should suffice your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  I recommend using L2TP as it's a newer technology (than PPTP) and is less vulnerable.  OpenVPN (the newest of all of the VPN's) isn't yet available on the iPad (as far as I know).  Setting up a VPN is pretty painless.  There are routers that do it, you can use a mac mini running Server, or a Linux box.